# iText- ColumnText set text fit size in Rectangle

Tags: java, itext

I want to add text into a rectangle(x,y,w,h). Text should be fitted size of rectangle (mean it has a maximum size but it still contains in rectangle).
I tried to measure the text size base on `BaseFont.getWidthPoint()` The problem is the final text size can't fit the rect. It looks like this:
[image]

Here is my try:

```
  PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    cb.saveState();
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
    Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont());
    int rectWidth = 80;
    float maxFontSize = getMaxFontSize(BaseFont.createFont(), "text", rectWidth );
    font.setSize(maxFontSize);
    ct.setText(new Phrase("test", font));
    ct.setSimpleColumn(10, 10, rectWidth , 70);
    ct.go();        

    // draw the rect
    cb.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLUE);
    cb.rectangle(10, 10, rectWidth , 70);
    cb.stroke();
    cb.restoreState();

   // get max font size base on rect width
  private static float getMaxFontSize(BaseFont bf, String text, int width){
    float measureWidth = 1;
    float fontSize = 0.1f;
    float oldSize = 0.1f;
    while(measureWidth < width){
        measureWidth = bf.getWidthPoint(text, fontSize);     
        oldSize = fontSize;
        fontSize += 0.1f;
    }

    return oldSize;
}
```

Could you please tell me where I am wrong?

Another problem, I want to measure for both width and height, which text completely contains in rectangle and has the maximum font size. Is there any way to do this?

**Update**: here is the complete source code that worked for me:

```
   private static float getMaxFontSize(BaseFont bf, String text, int width, int height){
   // avoid infinite loop when text is empty
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(text)){
        return 0.0f;
    }


    float fontSize = 0.1f;
    while(bf.getWidthPoint(text, fontSize) < width){
        fontSize += 0.1f;
    }

    float maxHeight = measureHeight(bf, text, fontSize);
    while(maxHeight > height){
        fontSize -= 0.1f;
        maxHeight = measureHeight(bf, text, fontSize);
    };

    return fontSize;
}

public static  float measureHeight(BaseFont baseFont, String text, float fontSize) 
{ 
    float ascend = baseFont.getAscentPoint(text, fontSize); 
    float descend = baseFont.getDescentPoint(text, fontSize); 
    return ascend - descend; 
}
```

Comment: *I want to measure for both width and height, which text completely contains in rectangle and has the maximum font size.* - do you mean as a one liner (which is where your current code is headed) or do you also want to allow line breaks to best fill the rectangle?

Comment: I just need one line text

Comment: In that case apply the fixes I mentioned in my answer and additionally don't allow higher font sizes than rectangle highs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The main issue

The main issue is that you use the wrong arguments in `ct.setSimpleColumn`:

```
ct.setSimpleColumn(10, 10, rectWidth , 70);
```

In contrast to the later `cb.rectangle` call

```
cb.rectangle(10, 10, rectWidth , 70);
```

which has arguments `float x, float y, float w, float h` (`w` and `h` being width and height) the method `ct.setSimpleColumn` has arguments `float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury` (**ll** being *lower left* and **ur** being *upper right*). Thus your `ct.setSimpleColumn` should look like this:

```
ct.setSimpleColumn(10, 10, 10 + rectWidth, 10 + 70);
```

### A side issue

In addition to the main issue your result font size is 0.1 too large; essentially this is an error already pointed out by @David.

Your main loop in your `getMaxFontSize` method is this:

```
while(measureWidth < width){
    measureWidth = bf.getWidthPoint(text, fontSize);     
    oldSize = fontSize;
    fontSize += 0.1f;
}
```

This essentially results in `oldSize` (which eventually is returned) being the first font size which does **not** fit. You could fix this by instead using

```
while(bf.getWidthPoint(text, fontSize) < width){
    oldSize = fontSize;
    fontSize += 0.1f;
}
```

Even better would be an approach only calculating the string width once, not using a loop at all, e.g.

```
private static float getMaxFontSize(BaseFont bf, String text, int width)
{
    int textWidth = bf.getWidth(text);

    return (1000 * width) / textWidth;
}
```

(This method uses integer arithmetic. If you insist on an exact fit, switch to float or double arithmetic.)

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question with a measure height method that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs here, both in

```
while(measureWidth < width){
    measureWidth = bf.getWidthPoint(text, fontSize++);          
}
```

1. You're staying in the loop until `measureWidth >= width` - in other words, by the time you escape from the `while` loop, `measureWidth` is already too big for the rectangle.
2. You're doing `fontSize++`, which means that after you've used `fontSize` to calculate `measureWidth`, you're increasing it.  When you do get round to returning it, it's one more than the value you just tested.  So the return value from the method will be one more than the last value that you tested (which, due to point 1., was already too big).

Comment: I has updated my answer. for the first one, because I don't need to get the measure width, so there is no problem when escape while loop. The second, I try to get the last max size, but it doesn't work, the last `t` character still drop in new line.

Comment: Right.  Looking at your new code - you've fixed issue (2) but not issue (1).  You are breaking out of that loop with a value of `oldSize` for which `bf.getWidthPoint(text,oldSize)` is already bigger than `width` - that is, it's already too big.

Comment: And you shouldn't change the code in the question - you should append any new code to the end.  Otherwise, it makes the question meaningless, and useless to any future users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent quite a while to implement such functionality using binary search method to find rectangle fitting font size. And today i stumbled upon an interesting method in iText...

It is quite a new method in iText `ColumnText`;

```
public float fitText(Font font, String text, Rectangle rect, float maxFontSize, int runDirection)
//Fits the text to some rectangle adjusting the font size as needed.
```

In my version of iText it is static. 
See details: http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText