# Correct text position center in rectangle iText

Tags: java, itext

I try to draw text inside rectangle which fit rectangle size, like my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769881/itext-columntext-set-text-fit-size-in-rectangle), I want text align center in rectangle.

The problem is display text has wrong Y coordinate, look like this one:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 150, 100 + 120, 150 + 50);
        cb.saveState();
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont());
        float maxFontSize;
        // try to get max font size that fit in rectangle
        font.setSize(maxFontSize);
        ct.setText(new Phrase("test", font));           
        ct.setSimpleColumn(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getRight(), rect.getTop());
        ct.go();        

        // draw the rect
        cb.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLUE);
        cb.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
        cb.stroke();
        cb.restoreState();
```

I even draw text like this:

```
        cb.saveState();
        cb.beginText();
        cb.moveText(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());       
        cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(), maxSize);
        cb.showText("test");
        cb.endText();
        cb.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLUE);
        cb.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
        cb.stroke();
```

And got the result:
[image]

So I wonder how can `itext` render text base on the coordinates? Because I use the same rectangle frame for text and rectangle bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. I'm assuming you want to fit some text into a rectangle vertically, but I don't understand how you calculate the font size, and I don't see you setting the leading anywhere (which you can avoid by using `ColumnText.showAligned()`).

I've created an example named [`FitTextInRectangle`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/FitTextInRectangle) which results in the PDF [chunk_in_rectangle.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/chunk_in_rectangle.pdf). Due to rounding factors (we're working with `float` values), the word test slightly exceeds the rectangle, but the code shows how to calculate a font size that makes the text fit more or less inside the rectangle.

In your code samples, the baseline is defined by the leading when using `ColumnText` (and the leading is wrong) or the bottom coordinate of the rectangle when using `showText()` (and you forgot to take into account value of the descender).

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. Because I don't read the api document  in detail so I don't know how to do with them. I think I will take a look again.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: The link don't work. Where is the code?